# Headless Edge Selenium Error: No browser is open

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge, headless

I'm trying to get Edge open Headless but I keep getting the error  'No browser is open'.

Here is the Python code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

def function():
    edge_options = EdgeOptions()
    edge_options.use_chromium = True
    edge_options.add_argument('headless')
    edge_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')

    driver = Edge(executable_path='C:/Users/ID75143/PycharmProjects/TestProject/venv/Scripts/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe', options=edge_options)
```

No matter what I put after the last line (I've tried opening a URL and maximising the window), it says it's not possible because "No browser is open". I've tried opening Edge in headed mode and it works perfectly then, but not headless.

Anyone have a clue of what to do?

Comment: Can you check the driver you are using is compatible with your browser version?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct driver.

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you provided, I found that you are using MicrosoftWebDriver. It is used in Legacy Edge, for more details, please check this: [What is Microsoft Edge Legacy?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy-3e779e55-4c55-08e6-ecc8-2333768c0fb0)

So I have to confirm again, are you using the correct version of Edge browser and Driver? Maybe you should try to upgrade them before testing.

Here is a simple test, and it works fine ( Version 91.0.864.48 ):

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"E:\Downloads"  #change the route you need
})
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
driver = Edge(executable_path=           #put your edgedriver here
    r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
m = driver.find_element_by_link_text("32 bit Windows IE")
m.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
edge_options.add_argument('headless')
```

do this :

```
edge_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It still says 'No browser is open'.